# RedirectToAction with unnamed querystring parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In MVC 2 I have a `RedirectToAction` call which I need to pass all of the querystring parameters. Unfortunately I can only find a way to pass named querystring parameters is there a way of passing all querystring parameters regardless.

We have one named parameter, id but we just want to append all of the rest onto the end of the URL without setting them explicitly.

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "enquiry", new { id = enquiryCacheId.ToString()});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'all the rest'? Is it a model (complex type)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass COMPLEX objects in URLs, so that kills the option of passing on Complex types in new { }.

One option what you are left with is to encode the querystring and then send that in 'id'. Say for examples, you have querystring as follows `name=rami&gender=male`. Then you can encode it with  `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`, then set it to `id=[encoded string]`. On the other action (retrieving side) you can get id value and then use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` to decode the string. Then finally you can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` to split the querystring into NameValueCollection.

If above suggestion is not what you are looking for then. you need to add all querystring parameters to new { } in the RedirectToAction(). If you want to customize it then you might need to go to [ASP.Net MVC Source code @CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) and make your own builds (which I think not worthy for this kind of requirement).

Answer (score 0):

I have an extension method that I use to modify the querystring of the *current* URL:

```
public static string ModifyQueryString(this UrlHelper helper, NameValueCollection updates, IEnumerable<string> removes)
{
    var request = helper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    var url = request.Url.AbsolutePath;

    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.QueryString.ToString());

    updates = updates ?? new NameValueCollection();
    foreach (string key in updates.Keys)
    {
        query.Set(key, updates[key]);
    }

    removes = removes ?? new List<string>();
    foreach (string param in removes)
    {
        query.Remove(param);
    }

    if (query.HasKeys())
    {
        return string.Format("{0}?{1}", url, query.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return url;
    }
}
```

But, if you need to modify an arbitrary URL, it should be easy enough to modify. You would just need to add a parameter to accept an arbitrary URL, and then instead of getting the URL/querystring from the HttpContext, you just split the passed URL at `?`. The rest of the code should work the same.